# in Qt Creator 6.4 or 5.12 cant use multimedia module

Tags: qt, audio, mp3, multimedia, qmediaplayer

I tried all Qt 6.43 / 6.6 / 5.13 versions
I also read the whole internet, tried to run many applications related to sound made from github,
QT += coregui
multimedia
When I type, nothing works and header files and source files are grayed out.
I am getting an Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia warning.
I tried to update with maintance tool and it didn't work.
I'm making a mistake somewhere

Question: How can I play mp3 in Qt 6 version and above. .wav also works, I'm in a good mood :)
Thanks in advance to those who will help
os:
linux/ubuntu 22.lts
kernel 5.13
Qt creator 10
Based on Qt 6 .4.3 gcc 10.3.1

Comment: did you select Qt Multimedia from the Additional Libraries when you ran the Qt installation tool? It sounds like it's missing from your install.

Comment: i selected it but not working. i will clear install